# Bug: New "Vote on more question" messages appear when voting on answers to your own questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting

"You haven't voted on questions in a while; questions need votes too" appears even on your own questions, which you cannot upvote. It should appear as a reminder only when voting on answers to questions that you can actually upvote.

Comment: Sounds more like feature request to change existing behavior, not a bug.

Comment: @Shadow - only a programmer would think that :)

Comment: Oh, cool! They implemented this? I love finding out about new features by people filing bug reports. ;-)

Comment: While my answer's opening fragment was applicable, I was speaking about a different message than what you are referring to. Ima withdraw my answer for now and try to do some extra research. Interesting to know that there's now a general encouragement message instead of just the "votes are out", but I agree with you that if its frequency is too high, it'll be very annoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fair concern, I just went ahead and added an extra check.

Comment: to be deployed today